# I was trying to navigate a page from aura components but got error like this

Tags: navigation, salesforce, aura-framework, aura.js

[image]

code to get pagereference from parent component:

```
var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
        console.log('getpropertyDetails pageReference'+JSON.stringify(pageReference));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are trying to access an attribute from an object which is null.

In the `getSelectedProperty` method object associated with the state attribute is null.